# Buffer and packets

Tags: java, sockets, serial-port, buffer

I'm using an event which is activated when X bytes has arrived into the buffer. Is the typical buffer(), available() and read() serial port methods. My question is, when you send a packet via wireless (or whatever medium) you can expect that the packet arrived with the total length at a time? or bytes arrives sequentially through the buffer forming the packet? Because I don't know If I need to use buffer() considering total packet length or using it considering the bytes that arrives which form the packet.
My guess is that the firmware first use the cheksum operation first to ensure that the packet arrived completely and then move it to the buffer. Isn't it?

Comment: sometimes even the length field can arrive fragmented. Look up "framing protocols".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serial ports and TCP connections are byte streams.  There are no message-boundaries larger than one byte.  You cannot transfer messages any larger than one byte without another protocol on top.